# How do I add the ability for the program to continue even after the first input is given?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Hailstone Sequence program and I want to add the ability for the program to keep calculating even after the first input and output is already printed. Basically, instead of re-running the program, you could keep giving inputs.

```
public class HailStoneSequence {
  static Scanner MyScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number to generate the Hailstone Sequence for that number. ");
    int num = MyScanner.nextInt(); //Taking input from user
    while (num>1)
    {
      if (num%2 == 0)
      {
        num /= 2; 
        System.out.print(num+"  ");
      }
      else
      {
        num = (num*3)+ 1; 
        System.out.print(num+"  ");
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: A bit of a nit pick, but you should change "MyScanner" to "myScanner" it is standard convention to name variable starting with a lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just surround the block of code with a while loop that checks if the input is for example 0, in that case 0 would mean the end of the execution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HailStoneSequence {
  static Scanner MyScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 1;
    while(num != 0) {
       System.out.println("Enter a number to generate the Hailstone Sequence for that number. ");
       num = MyScanner.nextInt(); //Taking input from user
       while (num>1)
       {
          if (num%2 == 0)
          {
             num /= 2; 
             System.out.print(num+"  ");
          }
          else
          {
             num = (num*3)+ 1; 
             System.out.print(num+"  ");
          }
       }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to keep your program running like so:

```
 System.out.println("Enter a number to generate the Hailstone Sequence for that number:(0 to quit) ");
 int num = MyScanner.nextInt(); //Taking input from user
 while(num != 0){
     //logic
     System.out.println("Enter a number to generate the Hailstone Sequence for that number:(0 to quit) ");
     num = MyScanner.nextInt(); //Taking input from user
 }
```

Then at the end of your logic take the input again. the program will continue to run until the user enters a key(in this case, 0)

Comment: `do-while` is more appropriate if you're going to repeat the prompt.

Comment: Do not duplicate code like this.  This is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String input = "";
do {
    // Your code here
    System.out.println("Continue?");
    input = MyScanner.next();
} while (!input.equals("exit");
```